# Different ways of creating function from string using eval

Tags: javascript, eval

Yes I know eval is evil but ...

Few times I saw a function being created from a string in few different ways:

```
var s = "function fname() { this.m = function(s){alert(s);}}";

//1
var x = new( eval("("+s+")") );
x.m("aaa")

//2
var x = new( eval('[' + s + ']')[0] );
x.m("bbb")

//3
var x = new ( eval(s + " fname;") );
x.m("ccc")
```

The first 2 are clear to me but I wonder about the third one.
Could someone explain how adding a name of the function after it's definition helps eval do the job ?
Also do you know any other ways of using eval to create funcions ?

Thanks
Szymon

Comment: `eval('(function(){return ' + s + '}())')` also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, with the `function` declaration (which is not an expression), you create the function and put it into the current scope:

```
function fname() { ... }
```

The closing brace finishes the function statement, and an expression follows:

```
fname
```

As the function is already in the scope, the expression `fname` simply refers to the function. And because the expression is the last thing in your eval'ed code, `eval` returns exactly that function reference.

Instead of `fname`, you could write the name of any function in the current scope, e.g. `alert`, which would then be returned by `eval`.

Comment: If it were a statement, it would contain an expression ([not allowed](http://es5.github.com/#x12.4) with functions). It is not, it is a [function *declaration*](http://es5.github.com/#x13)

Comment: Thank you, corrected it. I wanted to emphasize that it's not an expression.

Comment: Thank you both Yogu and Bergi To make it even more clear maybe we add a sentece saying that "to return something Eval needs something which return something (an expression)" Would that be correct ?

Comment: So you understood what I mean? I've edited it and hope it's now a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fname() { this.m = function(s){alert(s);}}
```

is a [function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572). Eval would create it, but not return it, so after it another statement is added that just evaluates to the function reference.

In the other two examples it will be a function expression (with brackets around, or inside array literal), which itself evaluates to the reference.